# Using my own map styles in Google Maps with mapId and Style created in in the Google Maps Platform console

Tags: google-maps

How can I apply my predefined map styles in Google Maps, using a specified mapId, while avoiding the automatic application of styles created in the Google Maps Platform console for that mapId? Currently, the styles I set in code are being overridden by the styles defined in the console for the given mapId.

Example

```
    var styles={showpoi:[{featureType:"landscape.natural.landcover",elementType:"geometry.fill",stylers:[{saturation:"0"},{lightness:"0"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"geometry.fill",stylers:[{color:"#68a8e3"},{saturation:"-55"},{lightness:"-20"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#68a8e3"},{saturation:"-55"},{lightness:"-20"}]},{featureType:"poi",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{visibility:"simplified"}]},{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{saturation:-65},{lightness:45},{visibility:"simplified"}]},],hidepoi:[{featureType:"landscape.natural.landcover",elementType:"geometry.fill",stylers:[{saturation:"0"},{lightness:"0"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"geometry.fill",stylers:[{color:"#68a8e3"},{saturation:"-55"},{lightness:"-20"}]},{featureType:"water",elementType:"labels.text.fill",stylers:[{color:"#68a8e3"},{saturation:"-55"},{lightness:"-20"}]},{featureType:"poi",elementType:"geometry",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},{featureType:"poi",elementType:"labels",stylers:[{visibility:"off"}]},]};

    var hide_show_poi_edit = localStorage.getItem('hide_show_poi');
    if (hide_show_poi_edit>0)
    {
        defstyle = styles["showpoi"];
    }
    else
    {
        defstyle = styles["hidepoi"];
    }
    document.getElementById("hide-poi").addEventListener("click", () => {
        $("#hide-poi").hide();  
        $("#show-poi").show(); 
        localStorage.setItem('hide_show_poi',0); 
        map.setOptions({ styles: styles["hidepoi"] });
    });
    document.getElementById("show-poi").addEventListener("click", () => {
        $("#show-poi").hide();  
        $("#hide-poi").show();
        localStorage.setItem('hide_show_poi',1);   
        map.setOptions({ styles: styles["showpoi"] });
    });
```

And the map with ID

```
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 14,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },
        center: latlng_2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapId: "123456",
        styles: defstyle
    });
```

Comment: Why do you need the map ID for? If you set a map ID, it will indeed override local styles. Also you cannot load the map with local styles and later set a map ID. The docs says for `mapId` *This parameter cannot be set or changed after a map is instantiated.*

Comment: I need map ID to operate with FeatureLayers and data driven layers

Comment: I see no option to achieve that unless I am missing something. Even a map ID with empty styles will override (reset) the local map styles.

Comment: this is a show stopper for me as well, as I need dynamic local styles and use advanced markers, but one excludes the other.